# Clojure JavaFX -- Toolkit Not Initialized error

Tags: clojure, javafx

JavaFX 8, Java 1.8.0_31, Windows 7 x64

I have a minimal JavaFX program in Clojure.  The `(ns...)` clause is able to import the required Java packages fine *except* the classes in `javafx.scene.control`, such as `Button` and `TextField`, etc.

I have to put the import for these after initializing the toolkit.  **Why can't I import these classes before the toolkit is initialized?**  I'm not actually creating any objects yet... so I'm guessing JFX is somehow doing something in the background while these classes are imported, requiring the initialization first.  Below is my complete lein project (minimized from the actual application where I saw this problem, and without all the nice macros that clean up the JFX syntax):

File `project.clj`:

```
(defproject jfx-so "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
  :main jfx-so.core)
```

File `src/jfx_so/core.clj`:

```
(ns jfx-so.core
  (:import [javafx.scene Scene]
           [javafx.scene.layout BorderPane]
           [javafx.stage Stage]))

(defonce force-toolkit-init (javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.))         

;; For some reason the following must be imported after initting the toolkit
(import  [javafx.scene.control Button])

(defn -main [& args]
  (javafx.application.Platform/runLater
   #(doto (Stage.)
      (.setScene (Scene. (BorderPane. (Button. "Hello"))))
      (.show))))
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had a problem with this. Perhaps it has to do with your `defonce`?
I do my imports first. But I do make sure to init the FX-envoronment before instanciating any FX-classes.  So after your -main-method I would put:

```clj
(defn -main [& args] 
  ;;body here
  )
;; initialze the environement
(javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.)
;; ensure I can keep reloading and running without restarting JVM every time
(javafx.application.Platform/setImplicitExit false)

;; then
(-main)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should say `javafx.application.Platform` shouldn't it?

Comment: I've done a lot of work on this.  To compile some classes, make proxies, etc., the toolkit needs to have been started before the import.  However the lein compile step will hang if the toolkit is running.  I've got a kludgey workaround involving threads and jvm-opt options in the project.clj.

Comment: Yes,  Carcigenicate, you are correct.  I have fixed the typo now.